# Delete an object from an array based on the value of the dynamic property names

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have the following array of objects which needs to be filtered based on the values but the problem is the property name is dynamic.

```
const data = [
  {id: 112, cat: 0, dog: 0},
  {id: 114, cat: 0, dog: 1},
  {id: 115, tiger: 5, dog: 0},
  {id: 116, tiger: 0, lion: 3},
  {id: 117, tiger: 0, lion: 0}
];
```

My desired output should be as follows:

```
const output = [
   {id: 114, cat: 0, dog: 1},
   {id: 115, tiger: 5, dog: 0},
   {id: 116, tiger: 0, lion: 3}
];
```

The situation here is i have `id` as a constant property. But the other two property name changes. If the value of both the properties (excluding `id` property) is `0` in an object, then that object should be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a combination of `filter()` and `every()`

```js
const data = [
  {id: 112, cat: 0, dog: 0},
  {id: 114, cat: 0, dog: 1},
  {id: 115, tiger: 5, dog: 0},
  {id: 116, tiger: 0, lion: 3},
  {id: 117, tiger: 0, lion: 0}
];

// Every key/value pair in object that is named id OR has a 0 value is filtered out
const result = data.filter(d => 
      !Object.entries(d)
             .every(([key, value]) => key == 'id' || value == 0)
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. IT worked out well in my code. But can you please explain ```every(([key, value]) => key == 'id' || value == 0)``` what this code does? The result should be if both the value  other than ```id``` property is ```0```, needs to be filtered out. But  why the ```||``` ? What is the purpose of using ```OR``` ? and why ```==``` instead of ```===``` ??? Sorry, I know I sound stupid LOL. But i just couldn't comprehend the full picture.

Comment: No problem, I will try to explain, but it is all a logic problem: so we want to check if `every` key/value pair inside the current object has the name `id` OR has the value `0`. Because if one of those is true for each key/value pair in an object, we can be sure that every value is 0 and that we ignore the id property. Now we would have the solution to find every object that looks like that, but we want exactly the opposite, thats why I put a `!` before the `.every()` function - to negate the whole statement and get all the objects that DONT look like that. Hope my explanation isnt too bad lol

Comment: @DeepikaDeepi if you dont understand it or need more info, just comment again and I will try to answer

Answer (score 2):

You could destructure unwanted properties and take the values from the rest and check if some value is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 112, cat: 0, dog: 0 }, { id: 114, cat: 0, dog: 1 }, { id: 115, tiger: 5, dog: 0 }, { id: 116, tiger: 0, lion: 3 }, { id: 117, tiger: 0, lion: 0 }],
    result = data.filter(({ id, ...o }) => Object.values(o).some(Boolean));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation sir , perfect sol :)